# Change navbar LOGIN to LOGOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm struggling to change navbar login link to logout when the users logs in, I've tried the following:

header.ejs:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
        
        <li id="register"><a href="/register">REGISTER</a></li>
        <% if (login_info) { %>
          <li id="logout"><a href="/logout">LOGOUT</a></li>
        
        <%} else { %>
          <li id="login"><a href="/login">LOGIN</a></li>
        <% } %>
      </ul>
```

App.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req,res){
  if (!req.user) { 
  res.render('home', { login_info:false });
  }
  else {
  res.render('home', { login_info:true });
  }
  });


error : Unexpected token 'else' in C:\Users\Ayal\downloads\final\secrets\views\partials\header.ejs while compiling ejs
```

Comment: Should there be a space in `<%}`, thus: `<% }`?

Comment: Just copy the mention code in one of my existing project. Working for me. Can you please share the file code in which you're using `header.ejs`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if(true){ %>
   <h1>foo</h1>
 <% } else{ %>  
   <h1>bar</h1>
<% } %>
```

correct format.